# WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted and Navigate - C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to modify a simple application which use the WebBrowser item:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var menu = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("SomeItem").InvokeMember("click");
  webBrowser1.Visible = true;
  button1.Visible = false;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  webBrowser1.Visible = false;
  webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
  webBrowser1.Navigate("domain");
}
```

This works fine, the page load and then after clicking the button the user is redirected to the desired location.

Now I'm trying to make this without the help of the button.
Simply put the button code inside the load function didn't help, so I've introduced in my code the DocumentCompleted event.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
        webBrowser1.Navigate("SomeDomain");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentComplete);    
    }

 private void wb_DocumentComplete(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;
        wb.Document.GetElementById("SomeItem").InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

By debugging it, I saw that the wb object is correctly instantiated with the "domain" but I got `System.NullReferenceException` when I try to retrieve `SomeItem`.

The document is not fully loaded because I'm still in the load function ?

Comment: DocumentCompleted signals that the web page download is completed, it however doesn't tell you anything about the execution state of Javascript embedded in the page.  Which probably tinkers with this button, possibly as a bot counter-measure.  Looping and sleeping until GetElementById() no longer returns null might be a workaround.

Comment: Still nothing, I did a spin-lock loop on the variable but It never quit from the loop.